# are there any easy ways to replace hundreds of placeholders in the text

Tags: karate

I am creating a text file, which I need to replace lots of IDs for different lines dynamically. I notice the usage of "replace" keyword, however, as for thousands of placeholder replacement, it's not good idea to write all in the feature.

**I create a template file(NTSH.A01) like this(in fact, there are thousands of lines):**

```
SEQ  PAT  WELL  COUNTS CONC PLATENR   CODE
29   13  A04    14033   3.6       1    L
32   14  A05    2993    5.4       1    M
32   15  A06    2993    9.4       1    H
33   17  A07    2993    9     1  <barcode0>
33   17  A08    2993    9     1  <barcode1>
33   17  A09    2993    9     1  <barcode2>
33   17  A10    2993    9     1  <barcode3>
33   17  A11    2993    9     1  <barcode4>
33   17  A12    2993    9     1  <barcode5>
33   17  B01    2993    9     1  <barcode6>
33   17  B02    2993    9     1  <barcode7>
 ......
```

**my feature file:**

```
Scenario:
    * def textContent = karate.readAsString('classpath:resources/NTSH.A01')

    * replace textContent
            |token   |value |
            |barcode0|0     |
            |barcode1|1     |
            |barcode2|2     |
            |barcode3|3     |
            |barcode4|4     |
            |barcode5|5     |
            |barcode6|6     |
            |barcode7|7     |
              ......
```

If there are thousands of replacements, it's not a good idea writing here in the scenario section within the feature file

Comment: I think you could call a javascript function to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where you can start writing small pieces of JavaScript or even Java code to do what you want. Here is one possible way:

```
* def data = karate.readAsString('classpath:resources/NTSH.A01')
* def fun = function(n){ var temp = data.replace('<barcode' + n + '>', n + ''); karate.set('data', temp) }
* eval karate.repeat(8, fun)
```

The `data.replace()` is actually the same `replace()` method on a Java `String` object. Refer to the docs on "Java interop" if you want to know more.